# show alert only once on checked checkbox

Tags: typescript, ionic2, localforage

I have an checkbox which I can check and than show an alert where I ask if they know it for sure. So when they agree on the alert all exercises turn to done.

The issue: I set an local storage item `didAllExercises` so when I reopen the app I get this item and if this is true than set the checkbox to true but I have an `(onChange) event` on my checkbox and check if the checkbox is checked than show alert. So the alert shows everytime when I reopen the app and the item of `didAllExercises` is true

Here is the checkbox: `<ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="cheatCheckbox" (ionChange)="cheatButton(cheatCheckbox)"></ion-checkbox>`

And this is my `cheatButton()`:

```
cheatButton(cheatCheckbox: boolean){

    if(cheatCheckbox){
      localForage.setItem("showAlert", true);
      console.log('ccTrue', cheatCheckbox);

      //DONT SHOW ALERT WHEN ALLEX ARE DONE AND YOU CLOSE AND OPENS THE APP AGAIN AND NAVIGATE TO OEFENINGEN

      setTimeout(() => {        
        localForage.getItem("showAlert", (err, value) => {
          if(value){
            this.showAlert = value;

            console.log('!notRun', value);
          }
        })
      },400)

      setTimeout(() => { 
              let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                  title: 'Voltooi alle oefeninen',
                  message: 'Weet je zeker dat je alle oefeningen gedaan hebt?',
                  buttons: [
                    {
                      text: 'Nee',
                      role: 'cancel',
                      handler: () => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                        this.cheatCheckbox = false;
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      text: 'Ja ik weet het zeker!',
                      handler: () => {
                        this.allExercisesDone = true;
                        localForage.setItem('didAllExercises', [true, this.data]);              
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                });

                alert.present();
      },400)
    }    
  }
```

And here I call the `getItem method` in the `ionViewWillEnter`:

```
 localForage.getItem('didAllExercises', (err, value) => {
    if(value){
      this.cheatCheckbox =  true;
     }
})
```

How can I fix this issue to only show up the alert once you clicked on it and than reopen the app an set the checkbox to true without showing this same alert??

Comment: Are you saying setting `this.cheatCheckbox =  true;` in `localForage.getItem` triggers your `cheatButton` function?

Comment: @Ari yes the `cheatButton` function gets triggered by checkbox on true

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `ionViewWillEnter`, I would call `localForage.getItem` in the `constructor`. If that didn't fix your issue, you can use a flag called checkBoxInitialized, initialize it to true in `constructor`, and then use it as follows:

```
localForage.getItem('didAllExercises', (err, value) => {
    if(value){
      this.cheatCheckbox =  true;
     } else {
      this.cheatCheckbox =  false;
     }
    this.checkBoxInitialized = false;
})
```

Then modify cheatButton to:

```
cheatButton(cheatCheckbox: boolean){

    if(cheatCheckbox && this.checkBoxInitialized){ 
    ...

    }else
       this.checkBoxInitialized = true;
```

BTW, why do you pass `cheatCheckbox`  to `cheatButton` as a parameter? You can always use `this.cheatCheckbox`.

Comment: but than again if I reopen the app and all exercises are done so `value = true` than it will show the alert again